Is application.properties deprecated for configuring microservices gateways?
I recently completed a tutorial from 3 months ago, but the configuration advised for the API gateway isn't working as expected. I'm encountering a 404 error when trying to access /quiz-services. Can someone guide me?
Here's the configuration I'm using in my API-GATEWAY application:
server.port=8083
spring.application.name=API-GATEWAY
logging.level.org.springframework=debug

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=QUIZ-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://QUIZ-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/quiz/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=QUESTION-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://QUESTION-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/question/**



"the API gateway isn't working as expected. I'm encountering a 404 error when trying to access /quiz-services. Can someone guide" What is the expected result, and what is the actual result?

Wrong dependency was injected in my pom.xml file. Make sure you dependency looks like this
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
</dependency>

Please notice that artifactId is:
spring-cloud-starter-gateway

and Not:
spring-cloud-starter-gateway-**mvc**

as -mvc has depricated form spring 3.x
